# Move semantics and windows handles. DeleteObject-safe handle?

Tags: c++, windows, bitmap, move-semantics

Is there some kind of NULL Handle in Windows? If I create a bmp via `CreateCompatibleBitmap()` and delete it via `DeleteObject()` and want to use move semantics, I want to make sure that the bitmap is not destroyed. Hence I have to set the `HBITMAP` to a value that is secure to delete. Like `delete nullptr`.

Comment: An `HBITMAP` is a `void *`, so `nullptr` is a perfectly assignable value for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bad news first. For historic reasons, there is no generally valid "invalid handle" value in the Windows API. Different subsystems in Windows consider either `NULL` or `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` as the invalid handle value (both for returning an invalid handle value and for taking one). [Related article on Old New Thing](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/03/02/82639.aspx).

However, the **good news** is that although you still need to be prepared for unexpected return values (unless you dig through the documentation for every single function you use), providing either invalid value still always "works" in practice.
You might not have used the correct designated "invalid" value, but it's still invalid, and thus the function will fail. Your application will not crash, there are no negative consequences other than having wasted a few CPU cycles.

Therefore, go ahead and use `NULL` (or `nullptr`), you're good with that. If nothing else, it's intuitive for someone reading your code later. In your concrete example, *it's also the correct thing*, since GDI functions assume `NULL` as invalid.

You can pretty much rely that both `NULL` and `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` are invalid values. Although I'm not aware of a requirement (as in, explicitly stated in the documentation) that a valid `HANDLE` must be non-zero, in practice they always are. I'm willing to bet you will not find a handle with the value zero, ever (just try and use Sysinternals' `handle` tool, no single process on your computer will probably have a handle lower than 20).

But even assuming that `NULL` can be a valid handle value, you have to consider that some handles are already opened and closed even before `main` is called or global constructors are run, you really don't have a choice. That means that assuming `NULL` could be a valid handle, and asssuming it was still valid at the time your program runs, the chance that this hypothetical handle is incidentially of a type compatible with the API function is very low.

On the other hand, one might argue that an application might have `(unsigned) -1` handles open, rendering `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` a *valid* value.

Unless you are leaking handles, I cannot imagine how you would ever get that many open handles. But more importantly, long before hitting that number, you'll probably run out of memory on a 64 bit system, and you'll definitively run out of address space on a 32 bit system.
If `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` being a valid handle ever becomes an issue, you have a much more serious problem.

Comment: Do you have an opinion as to whether it should be `DeleteObject(x)` or `if (x) DeleteObject(x)`?

Comment: `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` *is* a valid input to many APIs.  It's defined as `(HANDLE)(-1)` and [so is the pseudo-handle for the current process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683179.aspx).  [Raymond Chen points out the potential for confusion.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/03/02/82639.aspx)

Comment: Furthermore, while Windows may be implemented defensively and not crash if you pass in `NULL` handles, Application Verifier does validate handles.  To get a clean bill of health (and logo certification) you shouldn't go passing bad handles just because it won't crash.  You'll also get a pile of kernel debug output, making it harder to find more severe problems.  To say "there are no negative consequences" is wrong.

Comment: Oh hey, you already linked that very same Old New Thing article.  Too bad you then contradicted it in your answer.

Comment: @Ben: you're fundamentally wrong, conflating "invalid handle value" with "invalid parameter". **for example**, the `IsBadReadPtr` function necessarily must support invalid pointer values as arguments, since that's the whole point of the function. in this case (and in the case of `DeleteObject`, where it's explicitly documented, quoted in my answer) an invalid value for the type, is a valid parameter value.

Comment: @Alf: But `DeleteObject`'s preconditions do not permit invalid handle values.  Only the return value documentation does, and that is to aid in debugging failure, not consent to having such invalid handles passed in.

Comment: @Alf: `IsBadRead/Write/StringPtr` is the exception... they specifically allow pointers into memory pages which aren't actually addressable.  And even then, passing an invalid pointer will cause a first-chance exception and possible debug break.  This is not behavior you want in a correctly-operating program.

Comment: @Ben, **cite the contract** that you are referring to, in particular the **preconditions**: quote them. i asked that before. then you did reply that it was not annotations, but knowing that it's not the documentation (it doesn't support your view), and not annotations, then whatever the heck is it you are referring to?

Comment: @Alf: It IS the documentation.  I've already quoted it.  The *hObject* parameter must be "A handle to a logical pen, brush, font, bitmap, region, or palette."  `NULL` isn't any of those.  That the postconditions (i.e. return value documentation) don't hold when the preconditions (i.e. parameter requirements) are violated is a universal principle of software engineering, and just in case there was any question I provided Raymond's explanation that shows that's how MSDN documentation is intended to be read.

Comment: @Alf: They could have written: "If you pass a valid handle that is selected into a device context, you will receive `0` as the return value (describing a valid input).  But `0` might also be returned if you pass an invalid handle; do not assume that a return value of `0` necessarily means that the handle is valid-but-in-use."  Which is a heck of a lot wordier and not as suitable for quick reference.  How is the argument description (i.e. precondition) not "about value"?  It tells you not only that is has to be a handle, but that it has to be a handle associated with a certain kind of object.

Comment: In fact, you can well imagine that the doc originally said "Returns 0 if the handle is selected into a device context and therefore could not be deleted." then someone encountered the other case and submitted an edit to include it.

Comment: well, fractal wrongness works that way, like inability to understand premise => conclusion: the documentation's *if* the handle is invalid, or ..., *then* return 0. Not "if return 0, then ...". that's not what it says. note, it does *not* say that. what it does say, is *if* invalid handle, *then* 0. premise. conclusion. that order. left to right. an implication, where if the premise is true, so is the conclusion. also known as [modus ponens](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modus_ponens). that's what the documentation says: *if* you provide an invalid handle as argument, *then* you get result 0.

Comment: @Alf: Looking at it as a logical argument is great, if you do it right.  It goes like this: "If preconditions met => (if handle invalid or in use => return value is 0)".  That can be flattened to "if preconditions met and (handle is invalid or handle is in use) => return value is 0".  What we're discussing is the case when the preconditions aren't met at all.

Comment: @Alf: As Harry pointed out, it may return `0` after some unknown and harmful side effect.  One such would be causing your Application Verifier test to fail.  You're in *undefined behavior* land, since the precondition is violated.  Even if there's a guarantee about flow control finishing the function with a normal return, whose value is `0`, which I don't think is meant to be a guarantee but an aid to troubleshooting, that still doesn't make it a good practice.  You'd still be in *partially undefined behavior* (everything except the return value) land.  A place I don't like to be.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: The second solution may be preferrable, though it probably depends on taste. The additional `if` has neglegible overhead, but it will make Ben happy, and it will in some conditions save an unnecessary syscall. On the other hand, I prefer straightforward code that doesn't have needless complexity. Almost all Windows API functions can succeed or fail, usually for 3 dozen reasons. If you pass an invalid handle, it will fail. It's arguable whether you break the contract with that or not. I can live with that, and don't feel bad about it. (cont)

Comment: (cont) It's a bit like not checking a return code when you know that you're not going to do anything about it anyway. When you're done reading from a file and close the handle, do you always check whether `CloseHandle` succeeded? Be honest :-) Of course almost everyone does not. You don't really care, and if it failed, what would you do anyway? Now you can argue that this is incorrect and may lead to the end of the world. Or, you can just say "yeah, I'm OK with that".

Answer (score 0):

There is no such safe value.  Passing anything but a valid `HGDIOBJ`, specifically one that is "a handle to a logical pen, brush, font, bitmap, region, or palette", to `DeleteObject` breaks the contract and could crash your program.  Or it could break into the debugger, especially on checked builds of the OS.  Or it could fill your hard disk with log messages.  Or it could cause you to fail AppVerifier and prevent logo certification.  Or it could trigger "appcompat" rules for your process and disable new Windows features "for backward compatibility".  Don't do it.

You can use `0` as a placeholder, but test the value and don't call `DeleteObject` if your handle is `0`.  This in contrast to `if (p) delete p;`, where the preceding test is considered a waste of code.

Comment: I think maybe you were thinking of `LocalFree`, conflating it with `DeleteObject`?

Comment: @Alf: The fact that sometimes `DeleteObject` is able to return a helpful result and avoid a crash doesn't change the violation of contract.  Passing anything except a valid handle to `DeleteObject` is a bug.  And specifically `DeleteObject(0)` is not permitted, per the preconditions.

Comment: I think maybe, when you cite "preconditions", you are referring to *annotations* instead of documentation. Well, you know, the annotations of `MessageBox` are wrong. And if the annotations of `DeleteObject` contradict the documentation, then also they are wrong. I hope you're not referring to annotations. But if you are, do keep in mind that they're extremely unreliable.

Comment: @Alf: The contract is that when you pass "A handle to a logical pen, brush, font, bitmap, region, or palette." as the *hObject* parameter, the function will operate as described and yield a return value as described.

Comment: And no, I'm not looking at the annotation macros.  Those are necessarily inexact.

Comment: I disagree. The return value documentation clearly states that if the handle is invalid, zero is returned. Thus, I think that `DeleteObject(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)` is quite safe.

Comment: @DeadMG: Are you claiming that "any input for which the documentation describes a return value is a valid input"?  Because that certainly isn't true for other Win32 functions.

Comment: I disagree. The multbyte function does not clearly document the circumstances under which "does not succeed" holds. DeleteObject, on the other hand, clearly specifies.

Comment: @DeadMG: Even if it doesn't crash when passed `0` or `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` (and I think that's true for compat reasons rather than by contract -- the return value documentation doesn't even apply when the caller has already broken the contract), are you sure that none of the other negative side effects I mentioned are possible?

Comment: Bottom line: if Ben's interpretation is correct, and you use Alf's approach, your program might crash or behave improperly.  If Alf's interpretation is correct, and you use Ben's approach, you've added a couple of bytes and lost a few cycles.  I think the best choice is obvious. :-)

Comment: @Alf: By the way, it's very interesting that you chose to mention `LocalFree`, because that has a great example of what the documentation looks like when `NULL` is allowed: "If the `hMem` parameter is `NULL`, `LocalFree` ignores the parameter and returns `NULL`."  Note that the wording "ignores the parameter" is included in order to convey a lack of negative side-effects.

Answer (score -1):

Generally 0 is an invalid handle, analogous to a nullpointer.

For example, `CreateBitmap` return 0 as an invalid bitmap handle, if it fails.

Consequently, you can safely call `DeleteObject` with a nullhandle.

From the [documentation of `DeleteObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183539%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> If the specified handle is not valid or is currently selected into a DC, the return value is zero.

An exception to this is a file handle, as returned by `CreateFile`, where `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` is defined as `-1`.

Comment: CreateCompatibleBitmap returns NULL on failure. So, I think that's better set to nullptr

Comment: @Chubsdad: in C++ up till and including C++03 there was no possible difference between `0` and `NULL` other than that the latter was only available via header file definitions, and that it could specify a size other than `int`. However, using `nullptr` you *require* that the handle type is defined as a pointer, while `0` makes no such requirement. In practice it a `HGDIOBJ` is currently a pointer, but AFAIK there is no guarantee that it is, so using `nullptr` is not a good idea.

Comment: -1.  I think that line of documentation is meant to describe the conditions that can cause the function to fail, not as a guarantee that the function will always fail safely under those conditions.

Comment: @Harry: what part of the documentation's "if the specified handle is not valid", did you not understand?

Comment: Read in context, the intended meaning is "if the return value is zero, the specified handle was invalid", which doesn't promise that the function will not raise an exception or cause other harmful side effects.  IMO, given ambiguous or doubtful wording, it's best to program defensively.

Comment: @Harry: that's not what it does say. in your creative reading the documentation's actual premise has become the conclusion, and documentation's actual conclusion has become the premise. i've heard of dyslexia (the late norwegian king Olav was dyslexic), but that's usually down at the letters and sometimes word level, not changing premises into conclusions and vice versa. so, not dyslexia. but what?

Comment: @Harry: re "Read in context", there is no other context than the earlier "if the function succeeds, the return value is non-zero". you're implying a context that isn't there. re "ambiguous or doubtful wording", there is no such. "program defensively" is all right, but the rest of your remarks is fantasy-land.

Comment: @Alf: Harry is right, and his reading of the documentation is [not only confirmed, but described as "so obvious that most documentation does not bother explaining them because these rules should have been internalized by practitioners of the art to the point where they need not be expressed"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/03/20/555511.aspx).

Comment: And then it's [reiterated](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/05/05/8459022.aspx).

Comment: @Ben: the documentation states what the valid parameters to `DeleteObject` are. the valid parameters include invalid GDI object handles. the documentation states what the function result then is. i.e. an invalid (GDI-object) handle is a valid parameter to `DeleteObject`. when you pass an invalid handle, the documentation states that the function returns 0. this is not the same as an invalid parameter. it is a valid parameter. i.e. the invalid handle is, by the documentation's stated function contract, a valid parameter. i.e. the blogs you link to are completely irrelevant. do you get it now?

Comment: @Alf: The documentation states what legal parameters are: "A handle to a logical pen, brush, font, bitmap, region, or palette."  Invalid handles do not qualify.  **The contract for the return value doesn't even hold when you violate the preconditions.**  If you think that the return value documentation weakens the preconditions, look at the [`MultiByteToWideChar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd319072.aspx) which says "The function returns 0 if it does not succeed.", yet it certainly can crash if passed a wild pointer.

Comment: @BenVoigt: the *types* of the arguments do not say anything about the *values*. the permissive *values* are documented by the *quoted line* in the answer. the `MultiByteToWideChar` function *is not* the `DeleteObject` function. the fact that you can crash one function A by passing an argument value not supported by that function, does not mean that you can crash another function B that supports that argument value, by passing that value to B. you're presenting a lot of FUD here. it's invalid. the answer cites the documentation. and that line is abundantly clear on what the function should do.

Comment: @Alf: I'm using the other function to evaluate your argument that "any input for which the documentation describes a return value is a valid input".  And I disprove your claim by counter-example.  Or are you not claiming that?

Comment: @Ben: please don't use "parahrase" quotes because they look like "citing" quotes. in fact they look exactly the same. anyways :-), your example was not a counter-example, because the part of the doc you focused on did not fit the criteria of describing some argument value. but that function's doc *does* have such a part: "If the input byte/char sequences are invalid, returns U+FFFD for UTF encodings.". This means that you can pass to `MultiByteToWideChar` an *invalid* byte sequence, which is a *valid* argument value by the function's contract. So, good function choice, bad doc part choice! <g>

Comment: @Alf: Fine, let's go with a little longer quote from the same doc: "The function returns 0 if it does not succeed. To get extended error information, the application can call GetLastError, which can return one of the following error codes:

ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER. A supplied buffer size was not large enough, or it was incorrectly set to NULL.
ERROR_INVALID_FLAGS. The values supplied for flags were not valid.
ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER. Any of the parameter values was invalid.
ERROR_NO_UNICODE_TRANSLATION. Invalid Unicode was found in a string."

Comment: It seems that according to your approach, you'd read that as a guarantee that any invalid parameter values cause `MultiByteToWideChar` to return 0 and a subsequent `GetLastError` to return `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER`, and that you can legally pass any value as long as you're fine with this contract?

Comment: @Ben: not "any invalid parameter values", not even "some". not a single parameter value can be invalid, relative to the function's contract (which is the only arbiter for what the function accepts). again it is quite a bit of FUD. conflating validity of parameter values with other validity notions. again, as an example, keep in mind that `MultiByteToWideChar` does accept an *invalid* byte sequence, and that that is a *valid* parameter value, with well-defined result, for this function. Not for some other function. For this function.

Comment: There's always a context!  In this case, the context is the MSDN Win32 documentation, which simply isn't precise enough in its use of English to safely draw conclusions from the exact way in which a particular sentence is constructed.  (The problem is that there just aren't enough people who are both good at programming and good at grammar; the former won't understand the exact meaning of what they've written and the latter won't understand exactly what they need to say.)

Comment: @Alf: A pointer to a buffer containing invalid Unicode would still be a valid pointer.  And you'll get failure reported appropriately (although the docs have conflicting information on whether it's `0` return value and `GetLastError() == ERROR_NO_UNICODE_TRANSLATION` or `0xFFFD` -- I think that's abuse of the word *returns* and `U+FFFD` ends up in the output buffer, not the return value.)  But reading the docs to say that an invalid pointer has defined behavior?  That's skating on very thin ice even if the docs do talk about a `0` return value and `GetLastError()==ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER`.

Comment: @Ben: re your "an invalid pointer has defined behavior", well you apparently labor under very incorrect view of what a Windows *handle* is, as well as what an invalid pointer is. in some cases a handle can be a pointer. in the case of a GDI-object handle it's an index, IIRC, with current API header files, for the C and C++ languages, casted to pointer. but that internal detail is of *no significance whatsoever*, except as possibility of conflating things. i don't want to say this, and i have really held back, but the confusion you demonstrate and apparently labor under is overwhelming.

Comment: @Alf: The specifics of handle implementation (and yes I know it's an index) do control what the practical results of undefined behavior are.  They don't affect the boundaries of undefined behavior, however.  Even when it's trivially easy to differentiate `NULL` handles from valid ones, that doesn't preclude negative effects.  In fact debug environments (i.e. Application Verifier, checked build of Windows, etc.) frequently intentionally crash the application when it uses an invalid handle.  Even if passing AppVerify wasn't required to market in certain ways,...

Comment: breaking compatibility with debug environments is a very bad thing, because it blocks you from using those very useful tools to solve other problems.